# DEC to BIN using for and

Tags: c++, converters

I have a problem with made a function in c++ that will give me back binary number.

```
function(unsigned short int user_input, int tab[16]) {
for(ii = 0; ??; ii++)
 tab[ii] = i % 2;
 i = i / 2;
}
```

User insert DEC number and get back BIN.

Should i just type ii < 16 ? It's working, but is it correct?

Comment: Might want to guarantee only a 16 bit value by making user_input be of type `uint16_t`. This will be more portable and avoid a situation where the compiler/architecture specifies an unsigned short to not be 16 bits. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505828/what-is-the-short-data-type-in-c

Comment: it must look as i wrote. for example if i type 5 i get 00000000 00000101

Comment: Yes, your code works. I'm not suggesting that it doesn't. I'm suggesting that to avoid compiler implementation differences you might specify your user_input to be `uint16_t` instead of assuming that an `unsigned short int` will always be 16 bits.

Comment: So 'for(ii = 0; ii < 16; ii++)' is enough or can make look it better?

Comment: That is perfectly fine. I'm just pointing out a caveat that you might want to pay attention to regarding the sizes of various data types and that compilers  are allowed to create shorts that are larger than 16 bits.

Comment: For now i don't want to use uint16_t as you wrote.
Thanks for fast answer!

Answer (score 1):

That'll work but is a bit wasteful (if you enter 1, you divide 0 by 2 15 times). Also division by 2 can be "sped up" by shifting. Here's an alternative:

```
function(unsigned short int user_input, int tab[16]) {
    int idx = 0;
    while(user_input > 0)
    {
        tab[idx] = user_input & 1;
        user_input = user_input >> 1;
        idx++;
    }
    for(; idx < 16; idx++)
    {
        tab[idx] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can almost, but not quite, guarantee you that those divides becomes shifts.  But, while you are at it, you should get rid of that mod as well.  If you want to do bit twiddling, use `&` instead (which I am also pretty sure the compiler will do).  Mixing the 2 like this looks really bad.

Comment: Yeah... i saw while function here and on other sites, but my function must be on for.

Comment: Have compiler generate the assembly to know for sure.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Thanks, was half-assing it at work :). Edited to include your fix. As for the divides becoming shifts, that is only if your compiler is smart enough to figure that out. Most are, but why take a chance?

Comment: @mascoj, I'm 3/4 assing it at work myself - waiting for a compile.  Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat more compact version:

```
void function(uint16_t x, int b[16]) {
    for (int i = 0; i != 16; ++i, x >>= 1)
        b[i] = x & 1;
}
```

Note that this puts the least significant bit in `b[0]`.

To answer your question: Yes, `ii < 16` is correct. This causes the loop to iterate 16 times, with `ii` going from `0` to `15` on each execution of the loop body, during which you check the last bit then shift.