# How to fix "error: expected ; , or ) before" string parameter

Tags: c, shell, compiler-errors, malloc, expected-condition

We're trying to implement a bash shell in c for our project. Right now I'm making a function, addAlias, and its based on our AddToken function (which populates our strArray struct).

The strArray struct has a **char (string array) and int for number of tokens in the array. 
Similarly, the aliasArray struct has two **char and an int for number of aliases. Implementation was almost identical so I don't understand where the error in the addAlias function is coming from.

I tried searching Stack already, and moving the code around, but I have no idea what caused it.

this is from the header file:

```
typedef struct
{
    char** shortcuts;
    char** notshort;
    int numaliases;
} aliasArray;

void addAlias(aliasArray* instr_ptr, char* short, char* long);
```

this is the function from the c file, which should populate the two arrays with the shortcut and its alias given by the parameters respectively:

```
void addAlias(aliasArray* instr_ptr, char* short, char* long)
{
    //extend token array to accomodate an additional token
if (instr_ptr->numaliases == 0)
{
    instr_ptr->shortcuts = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
    instr_ptr->notshort = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
}
else
{
    instr_ptr->shortcuts = (char**) realloc(instr_ptr->shortcuts, (instr_ptr->numaliases+1) * sizeof(char*));
    instr_ptr->notshort = (char**) realloc(instr_ptr->notshort, (instr_ptr->numaliases+1) * sizeof(char*));
}

    //allocate char array for new token in new slot
instr_ptr->shortcuts[instr_ptr->numaliases] = (char *)malloc((strlen(short)+1) * sizeof(char));
instr_ptr->notshort[instr_ptr->numaliases] = (char *)malloc((strlen(long)+1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(instr_ptr->shortcuts[instr_ptr->numaliases], short);
strcpy(instr_ptr->shortcuts[instr_ptr->numaliases], long);

instr_ptr->numaliases++;
```

}

and these are the declarations from our main function:
    aliasArray aliases;

```
aliases.shortcuts = NULL;
aliases.notshort = NULL;
aliases.numaliases = 0;
```

this is all the code I added for this portion and when I try to comment it out and run everything with gcc -g, I get a few unrelated warnings but everything runs fine. 
When it's not commented out and I try to run it, I get these errors on it:

```
In file included from commandler.c:1:0:
commandler.h:17:44: error: expected â;â, â,â or â)â before âshortâ
 void addAlias(aliasArray* instr_ptr, char* short, char* long);
                                        ^
commandler.c:295:44: error: expected â;â, â,â or â)â before âshortâ
 void addAlias(aliasArray* instr_ptr, char* short, char* long)
```

Comment: `short` and `long` are reserved words in `C` (like `int` and `void`).  You cannot use them as variable names.

Comment: `short` and `long` are keywords, can't be used as an identifier. Try using some good editors or IDE which help you identify keywords/ident through colors

Answer (score 4):

That `char* short` and `char* long` are the problems. `short` and `long` are type names in C. You should use another parameter name.

Comment: Its always a good idea to include some links to add anorther layer of explanation. Like links to what is [short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505828/what-is-the-short-data-type-in-c) and link to further read [what can't be an identifier](https://www.quora.com/What-is-valid-and-invalid-c-variable-names) or include them in answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

`short` and `long` are reserved words in C (like `int` and `void`).

You cannot use them as variable names.

Suggested change:

```
void addAlias(aliasArray* instr_ptr, char* shortName, char* longName)
```

Now the variable names are `shortName` and `longName`, no longer reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (6.4.1 Keywords)

> 2 The above tokens (case sensitive) are reserved (in translation
>   phases 7 and 8) for use as keywords, a**nd shall not be used otherwise**.

and (6.4.2 Identifiers)

> 4 When preprocessing tokens are converted to tokens during translation
>   phase 7, if a preprocessing token could be converted to either a
>   keyword or an identifier, **it is converted to a keyword**.

In the function prototype you may omit parameter identifiers

```
void addAlias( aliasArray*, char*, char* );
```

In the function definition you have to use other identifiers for parameter names than keywords.

You can use for example the same names for the parameters as the names within the structure

```
void addAlias(aliasArray* instr_ptr, char* shortcut, char* nonshortcut)
```

Also take into account that the parameters should have qualifiers `const`.

```
void addAlias(aliasArray* instr_ptr, const char* shortcut, const char* nonshortcut)
```

Otherwise the function declaration will confuse users of the function and can not accept constant pointers though the function does not change the corresponding strings.